# Dependabot pip package-ecosystem with two separate schedules

Tags: dependabot

I have Dependabot running daily for `package-ecosystem: "pip"`.

The problem I face is that the AWS boto library has a lot of updates and this is inflating my GitHub costs substantially.

I should like to be able to run Dependabot on two separate schedules

- Daily for Python packages **except** boto and botocore
- Weekly for boto and botocore

Dependabot complains of a duplicate if I have 2 package-ecosystem keys set to pip so I am struggling to see how I can achieve this.